# How do we deal with duplicates of SO questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, exact-duplicates

Consider this question: [Fragment shader's output variables](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/4596/2654). If this were Stack Overflow, I'd have immediately closed it as a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9222217/734069). As it is, I basically copy-and-pasted most of my answer to that SO question, because it's exactly the same.

We know that CG.SE can have overlap with SO. So how best do we deal with circumstances where that overlap leads to duplicates? Do we just ignore it and accept it? Or do we do something else?

Comment: I strongly agree with Nero's answer that the same question may get different answers here. I also argued [on an old meta discussion](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/116/231) that even in cases with identical answers on both sites, the voting order may be different due to this being a community of expert computer graphics voters, which is another reason to allow a question here even if it has already been answered on another site.

Comment: (this is a general point - clearly it doesn't apply in this particular example where the top voted answer on both sites is from the same person)

Answer (score 3):

Ironically, this specific question also is an example of a cross-site duplicate of a question on Meta Stack Exchange: [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/246175)  But let's not get too meta here.

---

Basically, I agree with [Robert Cartaino's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/246175) and [malach's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4712/246175) answers in the mentioned MSE question.

So, if a question is appropriate here, we should keep it and answer it with the Computer Graphics background in mind. Depending on the specific question and other site, this may actually lead to different answers, or to answers which are similar but explain different aspects in more detail. Also, we could provide a link to the cross-site duplicate in a comment to give the user even more information.

This way, users who only know/found one site benefit from the information.

If the question is inappropriate here, we can migrate or simply close it.

---

However, **identical** questions, maybe even asked within a few minutes, by the same user, should probably be closed on sites where it doesn't belong and only answered on the most appropriate site. There are even more detailed information on Meta Stack Exchange ([Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/246175))